# 1002: Verification Error: Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiAddress

Tags: types, substrate, polkadot

```
1002: Verification Error: Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiAddress: RuntimeApi, Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiAddress
```

This issue wasn't in substrate 2.0.0 but after upgrading the runtime to 2.0.1 so facing this error.

You can produce this issue while using the below repo.
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/v2.0.1

If anyone knows what are the types for this repo, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are implementing node-authorization pallet in your substrate node-template. You have to add below type in your developer console.

```
{
  "PeerId": "(Vec<u8>)"
}
```